# JavaScript: behavior of NaN as literal and stored in variable

Tags: javascript, nan

By pure accident I've stumbled upon a dfference between `NaN` and `10 / 0`. I'm interested in the reason for this behavior. Here is my code, using the console of FF 34.

```
//as expected:
console.log(NaN == false); //->false

//now:
function m(value) { if (value) { return 'hi, NaN is not falsy'; }} console.log(m( 5 / 0)); //->"hi, NaN is not falsy"
//of course:
console.log(typeof NaN); //-> "number"
//but:
function m(value) { if (value) { return 'hi, NaN is not falsy'; }} console.log(m(NaN)); //-> undefined
```

Thank you very much for any advice!

**::Edit::**

Alright, my fault:

```
function m(value) { if (value) { return 'hi, NaN is not falsy'; }} console.log(m(parseInt('hi', 10))); //->undefined
```

Comment: `console.log(5 / 0); console.log(NaN);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you divide the number by 0 it becomes `Infinity` not false.

Answer (score 0):

For an explanation to the WHY it comes to Infinity, it's because that's how floating point math works:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Infinities

(I had no idea either, but it does make sense when you read it)